# Some stuff related to the twin prime conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, pr.probability, prime-numbers

I am making three statements here, and my question is about statement 2, asking if someone can prove or disprove it. A (possibly weaker) version of statement 2 was proved as an answer to a former question of mine on MSE (and I provide the link to that question and answer below) but I really need to know if statement 2 is truly correct or not, as it has big implications if it is correct. So here we go.

I am looking at the sequence [A0028222](https://oeis.org/A002822) which is essentially the sequence of twin primes. I will be talking about all twin primes here, but it means all twin primes except $\{3, 5\}$.

**Statement 1**

Any number $x$ in the sequence A0028222 is a number such that both $6x+1$ and $6x-1$ are twin primes. Other than $\{3, 5\}$, this sequence covers all twin primes. This is a proven fact, and rather trivial.

**Statement 2**

Let $S_p$ where $p\geq 5$ a prime number, be the set of positive integers such that $n\in S_p$ iff $n\equiv \pm a_p \bmod p$. Also, $a_p\not\in S_p$. The number $a_p$, although irrelevant in this discussion, is

$$a_p = \Big\lfloor \frac{p+3}{6}\Big\rfloor.$$

Let $A$ be the set of all elements from the sequence A0028222. Then $x\in A$ iff $x\not\in \cup_{p\geq 5} S_p$. This is the critical part that needs to be proved, and my understanding is that it was proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202350/full-set-of-congruences-uniquely-defining-all-twin-primes). My question here is to confirm that this is true, because if it is true, the twin prime conjecture is true (unless statement 3 below is wrong).

**Statement 3**

Assuming statement 2 is true, then the exact number of twin primes (more precisely, elements of $A$) less than or equal to $z$, and denoted as $N(z)$, is given by the following formula:

$$N(z) = |\cap_{5\leq p< z} S_p'(z)|.$$

Here,

- $S'_p$ denotes the complementary set of $S_p$
- $S_p'(z)$ is the subset of $S_p'$    with all elements $\leq z$
- $|\cdot|$ stands for the number of elements of a set

The density of the set $S'_p$ is of course $(p-2)/p$. And because we are dealing with congruences across moduli (the $p$'s) that are co-primes (indeed, they are all primes), the density of the intersection of these sets is the product of the independent densities. The end result is this:

$$N(z)\gtrsim z \prod_{5\leq p < z}\frac{p-2}{p} \sim C\cdot \frac{z}{(\log z)^2} \rightarrow\infty, \mbox{ as } z\rightarrow\infty.$$

The symbol $\gtrsim$ means "asymptotically greater than". This is consistent with the Hardy-Littlewood first conjecture about twin primes (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#First_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture)), but even though my argumentation is based on congruential equidistribution and thus somewhat probabilistic in nature, if it is correct (or even not correct but fixable), this is a hard proof of the fact that there are infinitely many twin primes.

**Update**

One way to rephrase statement 2 (unless I am mistaken) is as follows. Let $x$ be a strictly positive integer. If $x\not\in\cup_{5\leq p< x} S_p$ then $6x-1$ and $6x+1$ are prime. There are no other twin primes other than $\{3, 5\}$.

**Update 2**

This should be my final update; if anything new comes up, it will be under a a different question. This is related to statement 3, and someone suggested that I try to see if it works for primes, before attempting to show that it works for twin primes. The purpose of this update is to provide a tentative answer to that question.

For primes, $a_p=0$, and $p$ must be removed from $S_p$. Ignore the fact that $p$ must be removed from $S_p$, and by doing so, we are undercounting the number of primes.

The result is this, unless I am mistaken:

$$N(z)=|\cap_{p< z} S_p'(z)|\sim z \prod_{p < z}\frac{p-1}{p} \sim e^{-\gamma}\cdot \frac{z}{\log z}  \rightarrow\infty, \mbox{ as } z\rightarrow\infty.$$

Here $e^{-\gamma} \approx 0.561459\dots < 1$. Here, $N(z)$ is the number of primes $\leq z$, and clearly (as stated) we are undercounting them, as $e^{-\gamma}$ should be replaced by $1$. Nevertheless, it still shows that there are infinitely many primes.

**Final update**

There are still erroneous statements in this question. A final version, after all corrections and new material, can be found on my blog, [here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/machine-learning-perspective-on-the-twin-prime-conjecture).

Comment: 1. Do you have a particular doubt about the proof of Statement 2 in the MSE thread? 2. The asymptotic statement at the end is definitely not consistent with the Hardy-Littlewood conjecture, the singular series (the attached constants) are different. 3. Sieve theory is a the theory that handles the estimation of the cardinality of intersecting conditions mod different primes, but it falls short from solving the twin prime conjecture. 4. There are several ways of expressing the count of twin primes in terms of intersecting conditions, e.g. as sifted values of n(n+2).

Comment: @Ofir: yes, I have some doubts about the proof of statement 2 in the MSE thread. That's why I am asking this question here, even though the guy who answered my question is certainly more math-smart than I am.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with statement 2 or its proof. All the difficulty is in statement 3.

Comment: I'll add some more comments. Considering the residue mod 6 just obfuscates things IMO. Given an integer $n \in (\sqrt{X},X)$, it is a prime number if and only if $n \neq 0 \mod p$ for every $p<\sqrt{X}$. Similarly, given $n \in (\sqrt{X},X-2)$, then both $n$ and $n+2$ are primes if and only if $n \neq 0,-2 \mod p$ for every $p<\sqrt{X}$. That's what statement 2 boils down to. Before proving anything about twin primes, I'd suggest trying to prove lower bounds on primes. If your methods cannot do that, then they won't handle twin primes.

Comment: @Ofir: good point, I should try first for prime numbers rather than twin primes, and see if I manage to prove that there are infinitely many primes using the congruential structure. That's the first step before attempting to prove that there are infinitely many twin primes. And if I fail at that, I would also fail for twin primes.

Comment: @Ofir: I updated my last formula in Statement 3, with $\sim$ replaced by $\gtrsim$. The unproved claim is now much more modest: there are infinitely many primes.